# Syntax Highlight and Autocomplete in Geany for GTK+ (C)

Tags: autocomplete, syntax-highlighting, gtk, geany

I have just started GTK+ coding in C.
I was curious whether i can get syntax highlight and auto-completion working for my GTK code...
because as a beginner it would be helpful.

I was completely convinced that it was not possible until i came across this video on youtube:

`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyeQrO1VDFM&feature=plcp`
I asked the uploader for help, but turns out his last activity on youtube was in Septembeer :(

I also tried opening the `gtk.h` file with geany as i had read somewhere that it worked, but unfortunately it didn't work too.

Any help? :'(

Comment: Is [this what you meant by opening gtk.h](http://superuser.com/a/399043/68111)?

Comment: Umm..no...i thought opening means just browse the file and open it? isn't it like that? if not please enlighten me... i'm new to gtk+.

Comment: almost, but you have do do a couple of things first. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create a file called `gtk_headers.c`. Add this line and save it `#include <gtk/gtk.h>`

Now run one of the following based on which version of GTK+ you are using.

**GTK+2:**

```
gcc -E gtk_headers.c `pkg-config gtk+-2.0 --cflags --libs` -o
gtk_headers.h
```

**GTK+3:**

```
gcc -E gtk_headers.c `pkg-config gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs` -o
gtk_headers.h
```

Finally, open the output file (`gtk_headers.h`) in Geany while your project is open. After a few seconds syntax highlighting and autocompletion will begin to work.

Comment: Thanks @Louis! That Worked....

I also found an alternative method which is generating gtk3.c.tags file through geany...and then load it..so that it learns the synatxes..
Thanks a lot!  
Btw, your method can be easily incorporated in  a script..so im going with it..

Answer (score 3):

Download [this package](http://wiki.geany.org/get_tags) and extract it to `~/.config/geany/tags`.

Restart Geany and you're done!